# Why is product reference showing title:sku as product title during registration?

Tags: commerce, users

[image]I am using drupal commerce, when I am putting an product reference for showing products to be added during registration: the title is rendered as title:sku.
But when I see the product in the store, it is showing fine.
How can I change the title?

I have installed auto sku, but I am not using it.

edit:
I have added screenshot

Comment: So maybe try to uninstall it?

Comment: I did uninstall it but, it did not work.

Comment: I tried on a vanilla installation still a product reference field on user/register is showing sku:title
I did not download autosku

Comment: This question doesn't really give enough information, like how you're integrating Commerce with registration in the first place. A screenshot of where the product is displaying improperly would also be helpful. Otherwise people just have to guess, and that won't be productive or efficient. : )